# Swift: Test if Segue exists, has the right destination and changes the right stuff

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to swift testing and at the moment I want to try four tests. I have a segue from a ViewController to another one (searchedForViewController). For this segue I want to test this 4 things:

1. Does a segue with the identifier "searchSegue" exist?
2. Does the segue get called then I tap on the Button Search?
3. Is the Destination of the Segue the SearchedForViewController
4. Is the Segue changing the variable "passedString" of SearchedForVC changed to "garten"?

My segue in Main.storyboard looks like this:

[image: Segue]

My code for the segue is like following (working, but for the future I just want to know how to test):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
            guard let controller = segue.destination as? SearchedForViewController 
        else {
                return
            }
                controller.passedString = "garten"
        }
    }
```

At the moment my test class is like empty and looks like this (just loading the view):

```
class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var vc: ViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as! ViewController
        let _ = vc.view
    }

    func testSegueShouldExist() {
        let identifiers = getSegues(ofViewController: vc)
        XCTAssertEqual(identifiers.count, 1, "Segue count should equal one.")
        XCTAssertTrue(identifiers.contains("searchSegue"), "Segue searchSegue should exist.") 
    }

    func testSegueActionsThenPushSearchButton() {
        // code here  
    }

    func testSegueDirectsToSearchedForViewController() {
        // code here  
    }

    func testSeguePassedGartenAsValueToSearchedForVC() {
        // call prepare and test after? 
    }
}
```

EDIT I found out how to implement segueShouldExist. I added the code. It calls the helper functioN:

```
func getSegues(ofViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> [String] {
        let identifiers = (viewController.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject])?.flatMap({ $0.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String }) ?? []
        return identifiers
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you need to restructure your code just a little.

```
# ViewControllerTests.swift
var capturedSegue: UIStoryboardSegue?

extension ViewController {
    override open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        prepareSearchForVC(with: segue)
        capturedSegue = segue
    }
}

class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var vc: ViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }

    func testSegueShouldExist() {
        let identifiers = getSegues(ofViewController: vc)
        XCTAssertEqual(identifiers.count, 1, "Segue count should equal one.")
        XCTAssertTrue(identifiers.contains("searchSegue"), "Segue searchSegue should exist.")
    }

    func testSegueActionsThenPushSearchButton() {
        // Can programmatically send actions to UIControl classes
        vc.searchButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

        // Just makes sure any segue was called
        // since there is only one in this case there's no need to be more specific
        XCTAssertNotNil(capturedSegue) 
    }

    func testSegueDirectsToSearchedForViewController() {
        vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: nil)

        // Attempts to cast the captured segue
        let destination = capturedSegue?.destination as? SearchedForVC

        XCTAssertNotNil(destination,
                        "Destination should be searched for controller")
    }

    func testSeguePassedGartenAsValueToSearchedForVC() {
        vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: nil)

        let destination = capturedSegue?.destination as? SearchedForVC

        XCTAssertEqual(destination?.passedString, "garten")
    }

    func getSegues(ofViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> [String] {
        let identifiers = (viewController.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject])?.flatMap({ $0.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String }) ?? []
        return identifiers
    }
}
```

What makes this work is changing your `prepare(for:,sender:)` method in `ViewController` from:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
        guard let controller = segue.destination as? SearchedForViewController 
    else {
            return
        }
            controller.passedString = "garten"
    }
}
```

to:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    prepareSearchForVC(with: segue)
}

func prepareSearchForVC(with segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
        guard let controller = segue.destination as? SearchedForVC
            else {
                return
        }
        controller.passedString = "garten"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The other way is swizzling but people might yell at you. :D